# Gravity algorithm help needed

Tags: 2d, lwjgl, gravity, slick2d

I'm using Slick2D and I was wondering if anyone knew how to tell if the player collided with the ground or a wall. So far I have it where it checks if the player hit something solid and if so it stops. What do people normally do?

Answer (score 0):

Well there's one easy way to create the object on the screen falling down.That's what I normally do.

```
fallingdown = true;
if(fallingdown){
imageY++; (or Y-- im not really sure about this..)
}
```

Okey, know our image is going down.Next thing we wanna is to collide when reach's the end of the screen.Let's say my Y of the screen is 200.

```
if(imageY >= 200){
imageY == 200;
}
```

Well...this is going to help you for the collision because it's not really easy to explain. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1qZk6dIW46Q